# How can I select the true expansion?

Tags: series-expansion, conditional

I have a series expansion which gives two results.

```
Series[-(1/  Sqrt[-1 + x + x z1^2 \[Chi]^2]) , {x, 0, 1}] /. y -> x
```

I want only the series which is true. I know I can do by using `Assumptions` or `Assuming` by discarding the other. But I want the other way i.e. Mathematica should pick the true one.

Comment: why can't you do `res=Series[....]` then type `Last[res]` this return the `True` part?  I do not know what you actually mean by `i.e. Mathematica should pick the true one.`

Comment: @Nasser I mean the true part of the result.

Comment: `series = Series[-(1/Sqrt[-1 + x + x z1^2 \[Chi]^2]), {x, 0, 1}];
Simplify[series, ! Im[x (1 + z1^2 \[Chi]^2)] < 0]`. Note also that `True` in `Piecewise` means that this is the default value, that means the values of the expression when all other conditions are violated.

Comment: The guys have already answered, what I want to ask is what is the point of the replacement rule /. y -> x ?

Comment: @Konstantinos. Oh  It has no relation to the question. I have used it for my own calculation purpose.